# Problemas al llamar al método con un objeto de una clase

Tags: python-3.x

Me estoy iniciando en POO. En el ejemplo que adjunto a continuación, relacionado con la "Asociación ", cuando llamo a los métodos obtengo dos errores diferents que no soy capaz a entender. Agradeceré vuestra ayuda

```
# Asociación
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def addNums(self):
        self.b + self.c

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, d, e):
        self.d = d
        self.e = e

    def addAllNums(self, Ab, Ac):
        x = self.d + self.e + Ab + Ac
        return x

ting = A("yo", 2, 6)
ling = B(5, 9)

print (ling.addAllNums(ting.b, ting.c))

print (ting)
print (ting.a, ting.b, ting.c)
```

Al ejecutar el código que pongo a continuación, obtengo errores.

```
# ¿No debería sumar b+c = 2+6?
print (ting.addNums())

OUT: None

# No debería sumar 4+5?
print (ting.addNums(3, 4, 5))

*TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-11c2791a7718> in <module>
      1 # No debería sumar 4+5?
----> 2 print (ting.addNums(3, 4, 5))
TypeError: addNums() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te voy a realizar las siguientes modificaciones en el código:

- Quito la palabra `object` de la clase, ya que en Python 3 no es necesaria
- Quito los espacios que tienes en los **prints**
- Te devuelve `None`, porque la función de la clase `A` no tiene `return`, por lo tanto una función sin `return`, siempre devuelve nada (es decir `None`). Agrego el `return` a esa función para que devuelva el resultado.
- El error se debe a que el método `addNums`perteneciente a la clase `A`. No toma ningún parámetro, tan solo tiene el `self`. Por tanto a un método (al igual que a cualquier función) que no toma ningún parametro, no puedes pasarle ningún parámetro. `TypeError: addNums() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given` te indica que el único parámetro que toma este método es el `self` y tu le estás pasando 3 más.

**Una vez explicado todo, adjunto el ćodigo**

```
# Asociación
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def addNums(self):
        return self.b + self.c

class B:
    def __init__(self, d, e):
        self.d = d
        self.e = e

    def addAllNums(self, Ab, Ac):
        x = self.d + self.e + Ab + Ac
        return x #Añadimos el return

ting = A("yo", 2, 6)
ling = B(5, 9)

print(ling.addAllNums(ting.b, ting.c))

print(ting)
print(ting.a, ting.b, ting.c)


print(ting.addNums())
#print(ting.addNums(3, 4, 5)) Comentamos esto, porque como he explicado no tiene sentido.
```

Comment: Ahora lo entiendo. Efectivamente, los parámetros, si se quieren pasar,  se pasan a la clase y los inicializa el método  __init__ de la clase, no al método addNums(self) , en este caso. Gracias

Comment: También lo puedes usar con un método sin necesidad de pasarlo a la clase, pero es que en caso de la clase **A** tu has definido ```addNums``` sin ningún parámetro, por tanto si tu defines funciones sin parametros, no les puedes pasar parámetros. Si quieres pasarle parámetros deberás hacer como has hecho en la clase **B** con ```addAllNums``` en ese caso le puedes pasar dos parámetros, porque tú lo has definido así.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Tu aportación me ha sido muy útil para poder continuar mi aprendizaje de POO, con estos conceptos básicos iniciales bien fundamentados.